# AWS cli command to get the CloudFront ID and origin source if you know the origin name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

With the CloudFront origin name is there a way to get the CloudFront ID and S3 origin source?

The origin name is `umbrella--qa--cf-distribution`.

I want the Cloudfront ID for it.
I want the Cloudfront S3 origin for it also.

I found the following command which gives me the origin names for all CloudFront distributions:

```
aws cloudfront list-distributions --query "DistributionList.Items[*].Origins.Items[*].Id" --output text
```

Thanks for any help or input!